# How does 4 earthquake spells destroying any wall in clash of clans work?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How does it work. Is it like a fixed rule or is it supported by stats/numbers in game. Most importantly does it take fewer spells if it is upgraded ?

Answer (score 2):

Someone else already did the math (its kind of complicated) [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHFceDkU3pZKnBLDR9kDl7pE_6BM9iSODa_vsoWuHbU/edit#gid=0)

Earthquake spells do damage based on percentage of current health, spell level, and number dropped. Consecutive earthquake spells do less damage to buildings. Earthquake spells deal bonus damage to walls (increasing damage).

Regardless of the level, 4 Earthquake Spells will take out any level wall. And no less than that will break any walls. Must use exactly 4 of any level Earthquake Spells to remove walls. Four level 1 Earthquake Spells are able remove level 11 walls, same as level 4 walls.

The math is explained in Reply number 8 [here](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/733570-Quick-Guide-on-the-Fundamentals-of-the-Earthquake-Spell).

Comment: Where did he get the stats for EQ spell. On the info page level 1 EQ shows 14%. But he is using 12% for EQ level 4 (without multiplier). Also what is the minimum % damage before knockout happens.

Comment: @user568109 it appears the info is from before the buff to spells. i will update the numbers when i get off work. this link here has a spread sheet with damage calculations. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iHFceDkU3pZKnBLDR9kDl7pE_6BM9iSODa_vsoWuHbU/edit#gid=0

Comment: The maths doesn't work whatever the % is. If you reduce something by 99% repeatedly you still never get to zero! There must be something else like '4 spells does it'!

Comment: @Ray If I recall, earthquake will automatically destroy structures that are under a certain percentage. That's why when you look at the Excel sheet flow wall damage, it says "collapse" after the last line. The hp percentage of the walls are below that threshold, so they just collapse.